# I see a lot of _GLOBAL__sub_I__ also from unused and stripped functions, how to remove them

Tags: c++, ld

Having that very little project:

func2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

void myfunc2()
{
    std::cout << "Func2 called" << std::endl;
}
```

func.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "func.h"

void myfunc()
{
    std::cout << "Hallo func " << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "func.h"
#include "func2.h"

int main()
{
    //myfunc();  // intentionally moved away!
    //myfunc2();
}
```

The .h files only have a definition of the needed funcs.

The Makefile:

```
all: go

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections $< -c

go: main.o func.h func.o func2.o func2.h
    g++ -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections main.o func.o func2.o -o go -Wl,--gc-sections
```

If I do a dissasembly of my generated executable I got still two unneeded functions:

```
0000000000400560 <_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z6myfuncv>:
  400560:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400564:   bf 31 10 60 00          mov    $0x601031,%edi
  400569:   e8 c2 ff ff ff          callq  400530 <std::ios_base::Init::Init()@plt>
  40056e:   ba 30 07 40 00          mov    $0x400730,%edx
  400573:   be 31 10 60 00          mov    $0x601031,%esi
  400578:   bf 40 05 40 00          mov    $0x400540,%edi
  40057d:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400581:   e9 9a ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <__cxa_atexit@plt>
  400586:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40058d:   00 00 00  

0000000000400590 <_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z7myfunc2v>:
  400590:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400594:   bf 32 10 60 00          mov    $0x601032,%edi
  400599:   e8 92 ff ff ff          callq  400530 <std::ios_base::Init::Init()@plt>
  40059e:   ba 30 07 40 00          mov    $0x400730,%edx
  4005a3:   be 32 10 60 00          mov    $0x601032,%esi
  4005a8:   bf 40 05 40 00          mov    $0x400540,%edi
  4005ad:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4005b1:   e9 6a ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <__cxa_atexit@plt>
  4005b6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4005bd:   00 00 00
```

It looks like every file which needs iostream objects generate a function which is called during initialization. The section and the generated function gets the name from the first defined function in that file.

And if I don't use that function and it is not linked in the final executable, these `_GLOBAL__sub_I__xxxx` functions are still present. How can I remove them?

It looks very mysterious to me that every user of a an iostream object like `cout` will generate a additional initializer function. Is there any trick to get rid of it? I feel it is only needed once per executable but I see it multiple times. How to avoid it in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is the [`std::ios_base::Init::Init()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init) constructor which is called from every source file that includes `<iostream>`. The call guarantees that the streams are properly initialized before first use.

And because of the ["static initialization order fiasco"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) this initialization has to be present in all files potentially using the streams, because we don't know the order of initialization between different source files.

Comment: OK, every emmit comes per file not per function. I didn't catch that, because even the name of the init function and also the name of the generated section was the name of the *first* function. As a result we should use the global objects from ios very carefully in size critical applications. For my embedded system it is a large overhead because we have a lot of small source files here.